# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'df_hotel'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
perc_country_df_hotel = pd.DataFrame([df_hotel['country'].value_counts().df_hotel['country'].value_counts()*100/df_hotel.shape[0]]).T
perc_country_df_Hotel.columns = ['Count', '% Distribution']
perc_country_df_hotel

#then, 
df_hotel['country'].fillna('CountryWithBigPercentage', inplace= True)
```

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'df_hotel'

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO!

```py
perc_country_df_hotel = pd.DataFrame([df_hotel['country'].value_counts().df_hotel['country'].value_counts()*100/df_hotel.shape[0]]).T
```

Here when you are creating a DataFrame you're using a series to as a data source, but then you have another dot `.` which tries to access `df_hotel` as an attribute which this series doesn't have. Did you by any chance mean to have a comma there?